# urllib.request.urlopen error but equests get useful

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib, urlopen

This is my code

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
url ="http://acm.aliyun.com:8080/diamond-server/diamond"
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url )
# response = urlopen(url ) # still error 10061
```

URLError: <urlopen error [WinError 10061] 由于目标计算机积极拒绝，无法连接。>

But when i change the url , set url ="https://translate.google.cn/" success.

```
    import requests
    import urllib
    from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
    url ="https://translate.google.cn"
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url )
```

and when use requests useful:

```
import requests
url ="http://acm.aliyun.com:8080/diamond-server/diamond"
response = requests.get( url )
print( response.content)
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  Is it possible your first request was done behind a corporate or national firewall of some kind, or that you had an intermediate outage?  10061 means "connection refused".

Comment: Thank you .To a large extent because of computer network problems  and finally I overwrite the code of server.py ,